# Best way to notify multiple adapters

Tags: java, android

Imagine this scenario:

```
FragmentA extends Fragment{
....
AdapterA adapter = new AdapterB(items);
...
}

FragmentB extends Fragment{
....
AdapterB adapter = new AdapterB(items);
...
}

FragmentC extends Fragment{
....
AdapterC adapter = new AdapterC(items);
...
}

FragmentD extends Fragment{
....
AdapterD adapter = new AdapterD(items);
...
}
```

All this fragments are being shown through a TabLayout.

When an action is done by a user in, for example FragmentD, the adapters of the other fragments should be updated.

What do you think is the best way to do this "notify" to all adapters? I'm thinking to implement an observer pattern for this behaviour, but I don't know if there is a better approach to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observer seems like a solid idea. The problem with a canonical observer in this particular case is fragment lifecycle: you'll have to correctly subscribe/unsubscribe from the observable in child fragments. You also might need to deliver updates to fragments that are currently stopped. So I suggest you consider using an event bus like [this](https://square.github.io/otto/) or [this](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus) as well.

Comment: I didn't know about eventbus! :) It's perfect for this case I think. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Observer design pattern:

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/observer-pattern-set-2-implementation/?ref=rp

you will need an onbservable object that will provide 3 methods:
- subscribe(Observable o)
- unsubscribe(Observable o)
- notifyAll(Object updateObj)

and then an Observer object for each of your fragments - they should have an 'update(Object updateObj)' method to react when the subject/observable is changed.

first, all the observers/subscribers should subscribe to the observable.
when a fragment is changed, you can then call the observable's notifyAll method to notify the other fragments